# Как сменить цвет текста в pickerView в swift?

Tags: swift

```
    @IBOutlet weak var LabelWhat: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ProblemTypePicker: UIPickerView!

    let typesOfProblem = ["ануитентные платежи", "дифференцированые платежи", "вклады"]


    func numberOfComponents(in ProblemTypePicker: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ ProblemTypePicker: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return typesOfProblem[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ ProblemTypePicker: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return typesOfProblem.count
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Подписать класс на протокол `UIPickerViewDelegate`

И реализовать метод:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let string = typesOfProblem[indexPath.row]
    return NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: [NSAttributedString.key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
}
```